# RSA encryption issue in C#

Tags: rsa, .net

I have an api that returns me public key. Here is a public key sample,

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ9AMIIBCgKCAQEAoqB1N9kugk4UKYnbh0fcg3qYyYKP0m4B
MjWd05ReeAdj+7JRYDEKO6xthDdVSdRO1/2V+YtY8DnXWnxRaICwu8235s3imZCyqgYnomPWdY+F
K540oTz/zug+9wbrlzt/WQFUU4lPlQbzm/Gjw8XfaCozT0e3bnWQcD7rORCOyuJgwSGgREjTv1ss
pgEaKTMknii9vpGZLeAXwoeIYROhuT4IoIkPDhtY0/UZiCi6v7Ja2dmy53VlWIkcm3rcnSJdvpXr
OgiHvaNABHmeymNycNqd6WUaysBRheluQ86nq/2nZPW0gcvmYt5zbMMYX3yY/n2WtAKeNQBAEW1q
b0s6MwIDAQAB
```

Now I need to encode string a=1&b=2 using RSA algorithm,

```
var key = await GetPublicKey();
            var keyXml = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + key + "</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
EncrptedValue = CryptUtils.Encrypt(keyXml, "amount=1&currency=aed", RsaKeyLengths.Bit1024);
```

I am using CryptUtils class at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/CryptUtils.cs.

Now I am sending the encrypted value to another server but another server guy telling me that the encrypted value is not corect. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It depends what the protocol is. You didn't even tell us that. But what you did definitely doesn't look right: you're encrypting a string with textbook RSA, which no sane protocol does. Almost all protocols are [hybrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem): your public key is only used to encrypt a session symmetric key, with a proper padding mode (PKCS1 1.5 or OAEP). Look at the definition of the API to see what you should actually be doing.

Comment: @Giles, thanks. Can you please tell me more. I am newbie. The api provider just told us that get the public key using first api and encrypt string using that public key with RSA encrpytion. Any link or more information will be appreciated.

Comment: You still aren't saying what that API is or what protocol it expects. This isn't a security question anyway. You might be able to get help on [so], but you really need to say what API you're programming for, and show a complete program that attempts to connect to the API but fails.